# How to read images in a folder and store their class number and image data? Python

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network

I have a folder which consists of a 100 images all of which are png. The file name is 1.png, 2.png, 3.png ... all up to 100.

Currently what I did was split these images up manually into different subfolder (10 folders, 10 images each), each folder is a category (car, airplane, horse, dog, etc).

Instead of manually making 10 sub folders to copy and paste the images into each sub folder, I want to 
read and store their data according to their image name which corresponds to the index entry in a txt file.

The notepad file looks like this. Basically this states that 1.png is airplane, 2.png is also airplane, 11.png is car, and so on.

```
airplane
airplane
airplane
airplane
airplane
airplane
airplane
airplane
airplane
airplane
car
car
car
car
car
car
car
car
car
car
bird
bird
bird
bird
bird
bird
bird
bird
bird
bird
cat
cat
cat
cat
cat
cat
cat
cat
cat
cat
deer
deer
deer
deer
deer
deer
deer
deer
deer
deer
dog
dog
dog
dog
dog
dog
dog
dog
dog
dog
frog
frog
frog
frog
frog
frog
frog
frog
frog
frog
horse
horse
horse
horse
horse
horse
horse
horse
horse
horse
ship
ship
ship
ship
ship
ship
ship
ship
ship
ship
truck
truck
truck
truck
truck
truck
truck
truck
truck
truck
```

How would I perform such an operation to generate their class number (label) for deep learning purposes? This is what I was previously using:

```
def create_data(data_dir,array_name):
    for category in CATEGORIES:  
        path = os.path.join(data_dir,category)  # create path to class
        class_num = CATEGORIES.index(category)  # get the classification
        for img in os.listdir(path):  # iterate over each image
            try:
                img_array = cv2.imread(os.path.join(path,img) ,cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)                     new_array = img_array
                array_name.append([new_array, class_num]) 
            except Exception as e:  # in the interest in keeping the output clean...
                pass

def normalise(X):
    X = X/255.0

def append(data_array,X,y):
    for features,label in data_array:
        X.append(features)
        y.append(label)
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. If your images are in the same order as they are listed in the txt file then you already have a 1-dimensional array just by simply reading your txt file and feeding it into `np.array()`.

Comment: This is a really brittle, unscalable design. What happens when you have thousands of images - how can you check this? What if one image is missing - all the others get their category mis-interpreted. Maybe consider adding the category name/number into the filename so it moves around with the image independently of the presence of other images. Or embed the category in the `PNG` comment field so it is part of the image.

Comment: @MarkSetchell This is what was asked of me ... how would such an implementation look like?

Comment: @pavel how would it look like if I may ask?

Comment: You could set a comment with **exiftool**, **ImageMagick** or other tools like this `exiftool -comment="Category:car" 1.png` and retrieve it with `exiftool -s -S  -comment 1.png`

Comment: With **ImageMagick**, set comment using `magick 1.png -set comment "airplane" 1.png` and retrieve with `magick identify -format '%[comment]' 1.png`

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure if this is what you mean, but this should help:

```
import cv2

def read_images_and_labels(img_dir, label_file):
    with open(label_file) as f:
        labels = [word.lower().strip() for word in f.read().split("\n")]
    data = {}
    for (ind, val) in enumerate(list(set(labels))):
        data[val] = ind
    corrected_labels = [data[label] for label in labels]
    images = [cv2.imread('{}/{}.png'.format(img_dir, ind), cv2.IMREAD_COLOR) for (ind, label) in enumerate(labels, 1)]
    return list(zip(images, corrected_labels))
```

img_dir is where the images are stored and label_file is where the labels data is stored. based on your code replace the call of `create_data()` with

```
array_name = read_images_and_labels(data_dir, file='index.txt')
```

If you want to verify the labels, pass the data to the below function. Set the timeout higher / lower for longer / shorter duration (timeout is in milliseconds). A cv2 window with the label on the image can be viewed.

```
def verify_labels(data, label_file='index.txt', timeout=1000):
    with open(label_file) as f:
        labels = list(set(f.read().lower().split("\n")))
    for (img, ind) in data:
        lbl = labels[ind]  
        image = cv2.putText(img, lbl, (50,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,  
                   1, (0, 0, 255), cv2.LINE_AA, False) 
        cv2.imshow(lbl, image)
        cv2.waitKey(timeout)
```

Comment: Thank you for this it works! Is there a way that I can see that the correct label is being applied to the correct image?

Comment: Yea I added a function, You can run it passing in the generated data and the labels file to it.